# using exec with only some parameters of argv (using C)

Tags: c, input, exec, argv

I need to have an input that looks like

```
./a.out <exe> <arg1> ... <argn> <others_stuff>
```

where `<exe> <arg1> ... <argn>` is the input that I must execute as a separate process (the objective is to save the exe's output into a txt).

Saving output into a txt file isn't a problem, I just have to redirect stdout (using dup2, freopen, or something similar).

The problem is to execute just a portion of argv! Because exec's family functions (they are so many!) let to give as input whole argv, or specifying each arg. 
I'm writing over here because I can't solve the problem, so I hope you're going to help me (I googled everywhere with no success).

EDIT: I forgot to say that i cannot use system for execute the command!

Comment: @unwind OP did mention some unsatisfying googling.

Comment: @unwind [whynotpostthatcommentintheformofapropersentence.com](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `exec` accepts an `argv` argument as a `char*` array terminated by a `NULL` pointer, you can just use the existing `argv` and set the member after the last one you want to pass to `NULL`.

This does destroy `argv` - if that's a problem, you can copy it first (you'll have to allocate some memory for the new copy...)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a contiguous portion of argv, you have two options, you can (as you have tried) create a new arg array, properly filling it as so:

```
  char *params[argc-2];
  memcpy(params, argv+1, sizeof params);
  params[argc-3] = NULL;

  execvp(*params, params);
```

You could just smash `argv`

```
  argv[argc-3] = NULL;
  execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
```

Or if you don't have too many args, you can use `execlp`:

```
  execlp(argv[0], argv[0], argv[3], argv[2], argv[4], NULL);
```

Comment: I used the second one, because after that i don't need argv anymore. It worked properly with "ls" command, but with "mkdir" doesn't. It says "missing argument for mkdir" or something like that (english isn't my mother tongue)

Comment: Smashing `argv` looks simplest. "smashing" sounds bad, but doing it after `fork` and before `execvp` means it can't break any other uses of `argv`.

Comment: @Black27 use a simple "printargs" program to make sure you're using the args you want.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I solved the problem! Simply I did a while iteration from 1 to argc-2 instead argc-1...What a stupid mistake!

Comment: @dave In this approach is there any requirement that `params` reside in the heap, or could `params` be a local variable?

Comment: @gcbenison `params` may reside anywhere. As ugoren mentioned, however, smashing `argv` is easier if you're between a `fork` and an `exec`.